# Changing a function's behavior based on platform, pythonically

Tags: python, cross-platform

**Use case:**

Have to work with python `subprocess32` module, for timeouts, but the code may run on windows as well. The module documentation suggests

```
if os.name == 'posix' and sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import subprocess32 as subprocess
else:
    import subprocess
```

**The problem:**

I think the above method does not take into account that the methods like `communicate`, `check_output`, `wait` have `timeout` parameter only with `subprocess32` module.
All calls to those will fail with this method

I don't wish to implement 2 different variants of the same function, conditionally import modules and everything.

Looking for a pythonic way of handling this. My hunch says that `decorators` and `partial` functions should help but can't seem to figure the precise and concise way.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You may have to write 2 sets of code for different platforms in the parts of your program where the syntax is different. Use a similar if statement where behavior is different

Comment: I would want to avoid that, that is exactly what I mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I devised a super ugly way of doing this using `partial` functions

```
from functools import partial
from subprocess import check_output
import subprocess

if os.name == 'posix' and sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from subprocess32 import check_output
    import subprocess32 as subprocess
    check_output = partial(check_output,timeout=10)

def execute_cmd(cmd, args):
    command = []
    command.append(cmd)
    command = command + args
    try:
        proc_out = check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Failed to execute local command \nError code:%s, Output:%s",
                          e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output)
    # I wish to handle TimeoutExpired exception here, but then this won't be generic
    except:
        print("Command %s failed to execute on host", command)
        raise
```